# Mystery constant internal beeping from laptop hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, audio

I got a new laptop about a year ago (HP Pavillion 15) and within about a week some high-pitched but quiet 'beeping' started. The 'beeping' is irregular, lasting for ~0.5 seconds, sometimes not happening for a few days and sometimes happening at random intervals about 2 seconds - 10 minutes apart. The 'beeping' isn't coming from the speaker or a buzzer, but the location of hard drive.

The computer has HP 3D DriveGuard which does beep if the computer is moved around viciously but comes from a completely different location on the laptop. I haven't been able to find any information anywhere about this problem. I did take it into Currys/PCworld but they made no comment about it and refused to replace/repair it, even after hearing it firsthand.

My drive, a 1.7TB generic one is completely fine passing all CHKDSK and S.M.A.R.T tests and a 10-hour full-system check. The only issue with the drive is it's a *tiny* bit slow but that's probably due to fragmentation. I've just dealt with it for a long time and gotten used to it.

Googling the issue returns a shocking amount of results on the issue but no answer, just a 'return to store'. Too late for that now as the store refused to take it back. What could this beeping be and is there any possible fix to it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it regular or irregular? exact same pitch or slightly different each time? I guess what i'm trying to get at is- is it a feature of the HDD or simply the HDD in operation

Comment: @Blaine Completely random beep length, volume, pitch and intervals.

Comment: well then, that sounds like a failing hard drive to me. What does the SMART data show?

Comment: [SMART](http://i.imgur.com/5dsWyG1.png). Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern hard drives are supposed to make almost no noise (other than the spinning of the platters), so any noise is a red flag.

To put it very bluntly, that sound means your hard drive is going to fail. It could be as soon as a week or, if you are very lucky, as long as 2-3 years, but it *will* almost definitely fail, likely sooner rather than later.

While hard drive response times can vary widely in the real world (depending on the physical location in which the data is stored), extra slowness can often mean that the drive is failing because it has to work around its failures.

Your best bet is to replace the hard drive now while you can still recover all your data.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a failing bearing making a brief dragging / scraping noise, and it sounds like a beep because it's very small.  I suggest immediately backing up the whole drive and replacing it.  You can keep using the drive for a non-important purpose (NOT backup).